# App crashes on one view and when app again opens it crashes oon same view

Tags: android, crash

When app crashes due to some code mismanagement , App unfortunately stops error displays and we go to the home screen . When we launch that apk again and open the same view crash remains there . How can we stop it so that app does not forces if that test case is not generated again by the user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i know why app crashes but i am saying if in case the app is in play store and app crashes due to soem reason , so if user again opens the app it again crashes even view is not created again . Can this be avoided.

Comment: @ritwik please post your code so we answer properly

Comment: May be the errors started coming from server side(If your app consuming webservices) , webservices changed something and issue started coming.moreover after check the error can tell you better .

Comment: just fix the crash, isn't it obvious?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23353173/unfortunately-myapp-has-stopped-how-can-i-solve-this)